# How to Create a Timer Actor that receives

Tags: scala, akka

I want to create a Timer Actor that tracks the progress of the entire program (and also estimate remaining execution time). Since the timer actor will have to hold mutable variable aka "current progress", I think it should be constructed under the highest supervisor instead of being spawned by lower actors. So I created this:

```
object Entry extends App {
    val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Twitter")
    val sup = system.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
    sup ! Sentence(.....)
}

class Supervisor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case sen: Sentence =>
      val timer = context.actorOf(Props[Timer])
      val pcfg = context.actorOf(Props[PCFGParser])
      pcfg ! sen.copy()
  }
}
```

Then I have this lower actor that does all the actions:

```
class PCFGParser extends Actor{

   def receive = {
     case sen: Sentence =>
       //....business logic
        val ps = context.actorOf(Props[PatternSearch]) //create another actor
        ps ! sen.copy(tree = Some(tree))
        context.actorSelection("../timer") ! PCFGAddOne
   }
}
```

So at this point, I think it should send messages back to that Timer Actor. BUT HOW!? I tried actorSelection, but all I got were "dead letter" errors. The message was not delivered. And it also seems like this PCFGParser actor failed to send messages to both its child actor and Timer Actor:

[INFO] [06/03/2014 01:35:25.290] [Twitter-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Twitter/user/$a/$h/$a] Message [TwitterProject.PCFGParserMsg$Sentence] from Actor[akka://Twitter/user/$a/$h#11
90256968] to Actor[akka://Twitter/user/$a/$h/$a#-1918790382] was not delivered. [6] dead letters encountered.

[INFO] [06/03/2014 01:35:25.291] [Twitter-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka://Twitter/user/$a/$d/../timer] Message [TwitterProject.TimerMsg$PCFGAddOne$] from Actor[akka://Twitter/user/$a/
$d#-1685001108] to Actor[akka://Twitter/user/$a/$d/../timer] was not delivered. [7] dead letters encountered.

First, I admit there could be some error that's inside the business logic of this actor that caused this error (or really?? Could a dead actor triggers message not delivered error?) Second, what's the right way for this PCFGParser actor to send message to a distant actor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access your Timer actor via a relative path like

```
context.actorSelection("../timer")
```

you first need to name this Timer actor instance "timer"

```
val timer = context.actorOf(Props[Timer], name = "timer")
```

Another point, if you use `context.actorOf` within the `Receive` block, you will create new actor instances for every messages processed. I don't think it is what you want to do here.

For examples if the instances are unique per Supervisor actor, you should write.

```
class Supervisor extends Actor {
  val timer = context.actorOf(Props[Timer])
  val pcfg = context.actorOf(Props[PCFGParser])

  def receive = {
    case sen: Sentence => pcfg ! sen.copy()
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I still have this question: if I want to keep the record of progress, those working actors must send message to the same `Timer` Actor right? If I create 100 `Supervisor` actors, there will be 100 `Timer`actors and their internal states are all different right?

Comment: Exactly. If you need a unique Timer instance, create it before and pass its ActorRef as a constructor param of the Supervisor. Then all supervisors will report to the same Timer.